# Doxygen: How to reference a README.md file from my main page

Tags: hyperlink, doxygen, readme, filereference

I have a project structured like this.

```
OpenRGB-cppSDK
  doc
    Doxyfile
    main.md  -- Doxygen main page
  examples
    .cpp files with examples
  include
    public .hpp files
  src
    .hpp and .cpp files
  tools
    cli demo
README.md  -- github main page
```

Now i would like to create a clickable reference to the `README.md` file and `examples` directory from the `main.md`, but i cannot figure out how.

I've added the `README.md` and `examples` to the `INPUT` variable

```
INPUT                  = ../doc ../include ../src ../README.md ../examples
```

and i've verified that the `FILE_PATTERNS` include `*.md`.

However when i write a sentence into `main.md` like this

```
Basic examples are in the \ref README.md, more advanced examples in directory \ref examples.
```

doxygen tells me it was unable to resolve reference to README.md and examples, even though i can see  in its output it found the files

```
Reading E:/Youda/Projects/OpenRGB-cppSDK/README.md...
Generating docs for page md_E__Youda_Projects_OpenRGB_cppSDK_README...
Preprocessing E:/Youda/Projects/OpenRGB-cppSDK/examples/ContinuouslyUpdateColors.cpp...
Parsing file E:/Youda/Projects/OpenRGB-cppSDK/examples/ContinuouslyUpdateColors.cpp...
...
```

In the generated web page it shows a button "Related pages" with entry "OpenRGB_cppSDK" that takes me to the README file
[image]

but the reference to the README from main.md doesn't work.

I've also tried `EXTRACT_ALL = YES`, but then what happens is that the main.md page gets a clickable reference to README.md but when i click it, it takes me to a blank page that looks like this
[image]

Please, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Did you try the standard markdown way? did you try wit `../README.md`?

Comment: @albert Version 1.9.1. If i write `\ref ../README.md`, i get `warning: unexpected token TK_EOF as the argument of ref`

Comment: The warning could have been a bit user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version with the markdown type of link does work: `[Test with md type](../README.md)`

The full project:
**README.md**

```
# this is the readme file

this is the readme file
```

**doc/main.md**

```
# this is the main file

this is the main file


the test with \\ref no path: \ref README.md

the test with \\ref with path: \ref ../README.md


[Test with md type](../README.md)
```

**doc/Doxyfile**

```
QUIET=YES
INPUT                  = ../doc ../README.md
```

output in: doc/html/md_main.html

[image]

Why doesn't the `\ref` not work, from the documentation:

> 24.107 \ref <name> ["(text)"]
>
> Creates a reference to a named section, subsection, page or anchor. For HTML documentation the reference command will generate a link to the section. For a section or subsection the title of the section will be used as the text of the link. For an anchor the optional text between quotes will be used or  if no text is specified. For LATEX documentation the reference command will generate a section number for sections or the text followed by a page number if  refers to an anchor.

The "../README.md" doesn't constitute a valid name
The "README.md" would work when it is a local file (i.e. local to the `doc` directory).

Comment: Thanks. But do you also know how to reference the directory? In the top panel i have a tab "Files" which shows the tree of files with a clickable directory entry that leads to a page with description i added with `/** \dir examples blabla */`, how to create a clickable link to this page?

Comment: I don't think there is a diect way to do it. Best is to place  in the paragraph of the `\dir` a `\anchor` and reference this.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't work, but thanks anyway.

Comment: What did you try in this respect?

Comment: I did some tests as well and it looks like the `\dir` command is not seen as a command that creates a new page that needs local references (like e.g. the `\page` command does).